# Create a date object in a specific time zone and convert it to UTC in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, locale, datetime-format

My application is currently storing the date and time of a particular event in the following format:

```js
date: 2022-05-06
time: 00:00 // (12:00 AM)
```

Each event's time also contains a TimeZone associated with it. If the person who is organizing the event is from, say, Singapore, the **time zone** will be **Asia/Singapore**.

When I send a calendar invite of this event to its attendees, I want to send it in UTC time so that at the recipient's end, it will be in their time zone. (Note: I am using [ics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ics) package for creating calendar events).

So, what I want is to create a date object with `time = 2022-05-06 00:00` in Singapore TimeZone (according to the above example) and then convert it to UTC, which should give `2022-05-05 16:00` (since Asia/Singapore is UTC+8). How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some considerations on a similar topic have been made [here](/a/65785031), and [this](/q/17751698) could also be related, especially the linked questions.

Comment: Why not store the event as unix timestamp which is UTC by default? Would be much easier to convert.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to handle with date in javascript

Comment: @Tony ... regarding all the so far provided answers / approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach has to be built upon some pre-conditions

- the passed date-time string needs to be a parsable string which represents the local date of the to be targeted timezone, thus it does not include parsable timezone offset data.
- the timezone gets provided as [name which is conform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority)'s [Time Zone Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Then the implementation is as follows

- create a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) instance from a parsable date representative (either number or string value).

  - **Note** ... this date object already carries its own timezone offset determined by the client/environment the script is running at.
- In order to produce a later on easy to parse UTC-conform custom string format the approach utilizes the [`format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) method of [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) of [ECMAScript's Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

  - **Note** ... the configuration of the `options` parameter is set with the only goal of returning a custom UTC date time string format where one can easily parse the dates timezone offset from (not as timezone name as provided but as number values in the form **`'+hh:mm'`** or **`'-hh:mm'`**)
- The timezone offset's hours and minutes are retrieved via a regex ... **`/([+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})$/`** which matches the pattern at the string's end and [captures](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) the `offsetHours` and `offsetMinutes` substrings.
- Both string values get parsed into a minute based total number value.
- Now one has the minute based offset of the provided timezone name in relation to the date object's local/client time which needs to be compensated by [the date's own timezone offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)
- The final step is to create a new date with a corrected timezone offset in relation of the provided timezone name to UTC which is done on a millisecond base via the date's [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) value and the former minute based total in milliseconds.

  - Now one can choose to either return the date as [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) or as custom UTC conform string again via `Intl.DateTimeFormat.format` where one would choose e.g. `'lt'` (Lithuanian) as `locales` string parameter because Lithuanian supports the date format of **`'YYYY-MM-DD'`** (with the joining dashes).

```js
function createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  parsableDateWithoutTimeZoneOffset,
  ianaTimeZoneName,
) {
  const formatConfig = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour12: false,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
  };
  const date = new Date(parsableDateWithoutTimeZoneOffset);
  const format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    ...formatConfig,
    weekday: 'short',
    month: 'long',
    second: '2-digit',
    timeZone: ianaTimeZoneName,
    timeZoneName: 'longOffset',
  }).format(date);

  let [_, offsetHours = 0, offsetMinutes = 0] = format
    .match(/([+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})$/) ?? [];

  offsetMinutes = (parseInt(offsetHours, 10) * 60)
    + parseInt(offsetMinutes, 10)
    + date.getTimezoneOffset();

  // return new Date(
  //   date.getTime() - (offsetMinutes * 60000)
  // )
  // .toUTCString();

  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('lt', formatConfig)
    .format(date.getTime() - (offsetMinutes * 60000));
}

console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Singapore'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Singapore'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Kabul'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Kabul'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Istanbul'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Asia/Istanbul'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Europe/Amsterdam'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Europe/Amsterdam'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'UTC'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'UTC'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'America/Jamaica'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'America/Jamaica'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'America/Anchorage'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'America/Anchorage'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Marquesas'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Marquesas'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Honolulu'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Honolulu'
));
console.log(`createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Chatham'
) ...`, createCustomUTCDateStringFromLocalDateAndTimeZoneName(
  '2022-05-06T00:00', 'Pacific/Chatham'
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Not sure this always works around DST changeovers. The options for `const format = ...` can be just *timeZone*, *timeZoneName* and one of *hour*, *minute* or whatever since all you're after is the offset as ±HH:mm. Also consider `offsetMinutes = offsetHours * 60 + +offsetMinutes + date.getTimezoneOffset();`

Comment: Then you should add a note that it relies on the built–in parser parsing an unsupported format and as a result fails in Safari at least.

Comment: @RobG ... Thanks for pointing the Safari issue, I never tested it there. I'm going to change the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const date = new Date('2020-04-13T00:00:00.000Z').toLocaleString('en-SG').split('T')
console.log(date)
```